# Why are so many besamim cases decorated with flags?

Tags: shabbat, havdalah, besamim-spices

I've noticed the trend but just look up besamim cases if you don't believe me :)

Comment: There is no halachic significance to the case. People must just like it.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Matthew and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: The whole case is actually a castle, so the flag on top is the flag on a castle

Answer (score 4):

Tower-shaped besamim boxes first appeared ca. the 16th century CE and rose in popularity ca. the 18th century ([article](https://forward.com/life/427680/of-sacred-items-and-gorgeous-tchotchkes-the-havdalah-spice-box/#:%7E:text=Originally%20created%20sometime%20in%20the%2016th%20century%2C%20the%20tower%20form%20of%20the%20Havdalah%20spice%20holder%20gained%20popularity%20throughout%20Europe%20in%20the%2018th%20century) in the Forward).

The significance of the flags and occasionally bells is not known for certain, but [Rabbi Prof. Shubert Spero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shubert_Spero) has [suggested](https://www.jhom.com/topics/spices/tower.html#:%7E:text=The%20appearance%20of,bells%20or%20flags.) that when the besamim box is picked up during havdalah, it's given a little wave, causing the flags to wave and the bells to jingle, which in turn announce the mitzvah that is being fulfilled at that moment, similar to the role bells that adorn Sifrei Torah play. This practical symbolism may have been what popularized these boxes.